# Text alignment on an image gallery

Tags: html, css, image-gallery, text-alignment

Is there a way I can stop each thumbnail gradually pushing the text to the right as I progress through each hover on each thumbnail? You know so the text always remains in the same position for each thumbnail.

Because currently it does [this](http://gyazo.com/d673065cf067c62754f82a65d5733a2c):

And I want the text to stay in one position for all the images, instead of moving gradually to the right.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
 <div class="gallery_preview">
 <img name="preview" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 1.png" alt="" />
 </div>

 <div class="gallery_thumbnails">
 <div class="imagebox">   
 <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 1.png" alt="" />
 <div class="text">Caption for image.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="imagebox">
 <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 2.png" alt="" />
 <div class="text">Caption for image.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="imagebox">
 <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 3.png" alt="" />
 <div class="text">Caption for image.</div>
 </div>

 <div class="imagebox">
 <img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" name="img4" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 4.png" alt="" />
 <div class="text">Caption for image.</div>
 </div>

<div class="imagebox">
 <img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" name="img5" src="images/IMAGE GALLERY 5.png" alt="" />
 <div class="text">Caption for image.</div>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
.gallery_thumbnails img {
 height: 60px;
 width: 106px;
 padding: 1px;
 position: relative;
 }

.gallery_thumbnails img:hover {
 border: 3px solid #a22b2f;
 cursor: pointer;
 }

.gallery_preview img {
 padding: 1px;
}

.imagebox {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 }

.text {
 display: none;
 margin:-100px;
 margin-left:-150px;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:16px;
 color:white;    
 }
```

Comment: you could make a div and populate it on hover with jQuery?

Comment: Well I'm quite new to this so I don't know how to do any Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>When you say the text, are you refering to the .text? Not sure i understand the question but, if I do, wouldn't you solve your problem by giving said class an absolute position?</del>

http://jsfiddle.net/du7340L4/2/ I made alterations to your fiddle to give you an idea of what you should be going for!

```
.gallery_thumbnails {
    position: relative;
}
```

In order to give anything an absolute positioning it needs to be inside either a static or a relative element!

Once you have that, you can give `position: absolute;` to your .text class.

Hope it helps, let me know! Meanwhile, if you're learning css, learning about the position property is fundamental. Static, relative and absolute positioning may be tricky at first but you'll get the hang of it ;)

Comment: Yeah I mean the .text class. I could try what you said and let you know.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue, it still does the same.

Comment: Questions like this should be made in the form of a comment not an answer.

Comment: Maybe you could make a simple fiddle so people can experiment themselves ;) @starvador also gave a possible solution, just remember the position: absolute; if you want it to stay still, it's probably the easiest way!

Comment: Sorry for the misplaced "question", it wouldn't let me comment the original post on account of not having enough rep!

Comment: @Grant note that position absolute positions an element based on the previous parent who's position is relative or absolute. In other words, try making .text absolute and make the image thumbnails static.

Comment: Oh I did it but it didn't change anything, the text still moves.

Comment: Hmm unless I'm doing something wrong it just slightly pushes the text a little left but the same effect still occurs, of the text moving right as you progress through each thumbnail with each hover

Comment: Did you try to change your original code or are you talking about my alterations to your fiddle? They should work fine, works for me. I moved the .text a bit lower so we can see it better, with the "top: 100px;" line, you can position it wherever you want that way. But all captions are showing in the same place for me: left: 0, top: 100px, that's where they are! I even numbered them so we could see that it is showing the correct caption...

Comment: Ahh I think that has fixed the issue, I just need to reposition the text, but it stays in the same place. thanks!

Comment: Yes, with an absolute element you can position it with just left/right and top/bottom. The place I chose was merely an example. Glad it helped!

Comment: Could I also add like a bar that lowers the opacity of that image within the bar?

Comment: You mean like have it faded out and only fade in when you hover?

Comment: In any case you can either use the opacity property or use an rbga color system for the background-color property like background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) where the 1 is the alpha(opacity) value. the 0's are your normal rgb channels, i used 0's as an example. To overlay a translucent div on top of your images you can just use your newly found knowledge about absolute positioning ;)